# No matching bean of type ... found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, autowired

after some days of trying and waitin' for answers on the springsource forums I'll try it here.
Running my application results in these exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.example.my.services.user.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Here's the relevant code

application context:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test" />
  <property name="username" value="test" />
  <property name="password" value="test" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.my.entities.*" />
  <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" />
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

com.example.my.entities.user:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "tbl_users" )
public class User
{
  @Id
  @Column( name = "id" )
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  @Column( name = "username" )
  private String username;

  @Column( name = "password" )
  private String password;

  public void setId( int id )
  {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public int getId()
  {
    return id;
  }

  public void setUsername( String username )
  {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public String getUsername()
  {
    return username;
  }

  public void setPassword( String password )
  {
    this.password = password;
  }

  public String getPassword()
  {
    return password;
  }
}
```

service:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService
{
  @Autowired
  private UserDAO userDAO;

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public void addUser( User user )
  {
    userDAO.addUser( user );
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public List<User> listUsers()
  {
    return userDAO.listUsers();
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public void removeUser( int id )
  {
    userDAO.removeUser( id );
  }
}
```

Comment: We need to see the servlet Spring config too.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Multiple things can cause this, I didn't bother to check your entire repository, so I'm going out on a limb here.

First off, you could be missing an annotation (@Service or @Component) from the implementation of `com.example.my.services.user.UserService`, if you're using annotations for configuration. If you're using (only) xml, you're probably missing the `<bean>` -definition for the UserService-implementation.

If you're using annotations and the implementation is annotated correctly, check that the package where the implementation is located in is scanned (check your `<context:component-scan base-package=` -value).

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot! My base-package was com.example.my.web.controller because i thought i just need the path to the controllers. Changed to com.example.my to cover all needed classes (dao, service, entity, controller) and it worked well! oh and i've changed the session factory class to org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean and removed the configurationClass property.

Comment: In my case, interface was present but implementation class was missing. Added that class with @service and problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: Actually it was the package name.

Answer (score 13):

Add this to you applicationContext:

```
 <bean id="userService" class="com.example.my.services.user.UserServiceImpl ">
```

Comment: Thanks as well, because your answer helped me figuring out that it doesn't covers all my classes.

Answer (score 10):

Add annotation @Repository to the head of userDao Class.If userDao is a interface,add this annotation to the implements of the interface.

Answer (score 6):

I have similar trouble in test config, because of using AOP.
I added this line of code in spring-config.xml

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

And it works !

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but I was missing the (@Service or @Component) from the implementation of com.example.my.services.myUser.MyUserServiceImpl

Answer (score 1):

IF this is only occurring on deployments, be sure that you have the dependency of the package you are referencing in the .war.  For instance, this was working locally on my machine, with debug configurations working fine, but after deploying to Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk , I received this error and noticed one of the dependencies was not bundled in the .war package.

Comment: Could you also advise how to make the dependency bundled into the .war?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the wrong dependecy for CrudRepository. My IDE added also follwing:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I just needed:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I removed the first one and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but in my case, implemented class was accidently become 'abstract' as a result autowiring was failing.