# No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, sessionfactory

I'm a beginner in the Spring MVC. I encounter a problem "**No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.**" and spend a lot time.

I used maven build management. My project has a project that consists 2 module : springcore (jar) and springmvc (web app). And springmvc (web app) has been dependency spring core. In module spring core, i defined all package such as dom, dao, service and their implementation and i also defined applicationContext.xml in src/main/resources following :

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Activates scanning of @Autowired -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.netvn" /> 

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
         class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
         p:location="classpath:jdbc" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
            p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"                    p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="annotatedClasses">
                    <list>
                         <value>com.netvn.dom.Contact</value>
                    </list>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
         <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

ContactDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class ContactDaoImpl implements ContactDao {
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ContactDaoImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<Contact> listContact() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query q = session.createQuery("select g from Contact g order by id desc");
        List<Contact> contactList= q.list(); 
        return contactList; 
    }
}
```

ContactServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ContactServiceImpl implements ContactService {

    @Autowired
    private ContactDao contactDao;

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public List<Contact> listContact(){
        return contactDao.listContact();
    }
}
```

In springmvc (web app), i defined web.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.netvn.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.netvn.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.netvn.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
            p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

 </beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
    <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                 classpath*:*.xml
             </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
          <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 
</web-app>
```

Here is my problem when i try to run it in Tomcat 6.0 server

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.netvn.dao.impl.ContactDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
```

Can someone tell me, what is the reason SessionFactory can't be created by Web Application Context or any problem when i configured SessionFactory.

Any supporting will be appreciated.

Comment: hibernate version used

Comment: can you confirm whether the applicationContext.xml file is copied to the classpath and it is loaded

Comment: I used spring version 3.0.5 RELEASE and hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA dependency for my project. Any problem with my project's dependencies?

Comment: Show here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961275/no-matching-bean-of-type-found-for-dependency

Comment: looks like the annotations are not picking up as instructed with <context:annotation-config /> tag. This can be due to "contextConfigLocation" config param not picked as expected from web.xml.

Comment: Combine your dispatcher servlet and application context xml into one single xml.

Comment: Create a setter for the sessionFactory.

Answer (score 1):

In general issue is missing configuration/classes from class path whether library of your own. Check again for correct import and configuration:

1. Either use classpath scanning for autodetection of entity classes:
   `<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
   <property name="packagesToScan" value="test.package"/>
   </bean>`
2. OR MOST IMPORTANT : AnnotationSessionFactoryBean class requires Hibernate 3.2 or later, with the Java Persistence API and the Hibernate Annotations add-on present.

REFER : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html

Answer (score 0):

Try directly importing you application context into the dispatcher-servlet.xml (which is clealy being loaded correctly) as below.

`<import resource="classpath:WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml" />`

Answer (score 0):

Your sessionfactory is not getting initialized correctly.

Read your error where and what is being thrown. which is

> Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory

You need to have SessionFactory initialized correctly

Now how to test this is pretty simple. First remove the sessionfactory added in your code. Test if datasource is getting initalized correctly

Add datasource as autowire.
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

in your methods you can easily do dataSource.getConnection. If you are able to test with plain jdbc you are one step closer.

If your datasource gets configured correctly you can test your sessionfactory as 2nd step.

I do not think conext scanning is giving you any issue as it is saying autowired fail. So your datasource and sessionfactory beans are not correctly setup in the xml